# What's the energy-spread of the quantum Universe state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

If the universe were in an energy eigenstate then the expectation value of every dynamic variable A would be constant.

Stuff moves which implies that the Universe isn't in an energy eigenstate but a superposition of different total-energy states.

What factors drive the energy spread of the Universe state?

Comment: Even in classical GR, there is no coordinate-independent, scalar measure of mass-energy that is conserved in a cosmological spacetime. Since it doesn't make sense to talk about total energy in classical GR, I don't see why we should expect it to make sense in quantum gravity.

Comment: What would you suggest is the equation of motion for the quantum state?